# how to extract data from getJson?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

How to extract the contents of "data" and load them inside form inputs ?
the situation is like this, I have a data displayed, it's being pulled out from
a database table. now on that displayed data, I placed an "edit" link. now my problem is,
how to use this json thing, in order for me to be able to load the data of the 
clicked/to be edited data in the input forms ?

```
  $(function() {  

    //retrieve comments to display on page  
    $.getJSON("testfile.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {  

        //what to code here?
    });  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Traverse the DOM](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Traversing_the_DOM) then [Modify the HTML](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML)

Answer (score 0):

parse json coming from server using [jquery parser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) and then place data wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

if you have simple field value mapping returned back, following do the trick for you

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
   $('#'+key).val(val);
});
```

Sample data -

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "address": "address"
}
```

but if nested data is returning, you need to traverse you objects.

Answer (score 0):

I name my input fields the same as JSON properties. So if i have the following object:

```
{
    "foo": "",
    "bar": {
        "baz": ""
    }
}
```

the fields would be defined as:

```
<input name="foo" class="jsonItem">
<input name="bar.baz" class="jsonItem">
```

and JSON success handler would fill them recursively:

```
$.getJSON("testfile.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {  
    function(root) {
        var fillInputs = function(obj, prefix) {
            prefix = prefix ? prefix + '.' : '';
            for (var prop in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    var prefixOrName = prefix + prop;
                    var propVal = obj[prop];
                    if (typeof propVal === 'object') {
                        fillInputs(propVal, prefixOrName);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('input.jsonItem[name=' + prefixOrName + ']').val(propVal);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        fillInputs(root, '');
});
```

If you want to use the id instead of name, be sure to escape the dots in the selector:

```
prefix = prefix ? prefix + '\.' : '';
...
$('input.jsonItem#' + prefixOrName).val(propVal);
```

Also, since I was lazy, the above function does not take into account arrays in the JSON object, but that shouldn't be hard to add.